# Flutter - Api call receives data but shows null on ui

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a screen with Getx controller. On init i'm making an api call and assings the result to varible.

```
AccountModel? _currentAccount; // variable storing received data.
```

After Api call the response is stored in _currentAccount;

```
    _getUserDetails() async {
      else {
      try {
        final request = UserRequest(user: user);
        final response =
        await getUserDetails(request: request);
        _currentAccount = response.getAccounts().first; // assigns response value to this variable;
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
}


oninit() {
  _getUserDetails();
}
```

On ui i have this widget, which I'm passing the controller to it.

```
  CurrentPlan(
  controller: controller, // passing the controller to this widget. using the passed controller updates the needed fields in this widget
  ),
```

The response is stored in this variable. How ever if i'm using this variable on ui im only getting null. The value of this varible is not updating in ui, whats causing this? How can i resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Without more code (e.g. your UI Code and more of the API response parsing etc.) it will probably impossible/very difficult to help you.

Comment: Refer my code for api calling and getx controller. It helps you more.  https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_api_call_dio

Answer (score 0):

Use Future builder. I suspect your UI gets build before you actually receive the data